# Can SAS Explict Pass-Through Temp Tables Persist Between PROC SQL Statements + RSUBMIT?

Tags: sql, sas, temp-tables

Using **explicit** SQL pass-through, is it possible for temporary SQL tables to persist between `PROC SQL` statements?

I'm using my SAS 9.3 to connect to a SAS server too; so there is also `RSUBMIT`s. The code below is a simple example of what's occurring.

With this code, the temp tables are created, but it looks like after the `ENDRSUBMIT` the connection is terminated sometime in the near future -- however sometimes this code if fine if I run it straight through, but if I wait ~10 mins and execute the later part, the temp tables are gone.

The working tables are very big and transformations are much faster with pass-through, but still take time. Any way to make the temp tables a little more permanent on the database side?

```
/* EXAMPLE */
/* upload list to db*/
RSUBMIT; 
PROC SQL; 
connect to odbc as db (dsn=blahdb uid=&id pwd=&pass connection=global); 
execute(load table #mylist (NUMLIST '\n') using client file 'mylist' escapes off quotes off delimited by ',') by db;
QUIT;RUN;
ENDRSUBMIT;

/* Join with database tables */
RSUBMIT; 
PROC SQL; 
connect to odbc as db (dsn=blahdb uid=&id pwd=&pass connection=global);

execute(select *
    into #mylist2 
    from #mylist A 
    JOIN DBTABLE B on A.VAR = B.VAR
) by db;

QUIT; RUN;
ENDRSUBMIT;

/* download join into SAS*/
RSUBMIT; 
PROC SQL; 
connect to odbc as db (dsn=blahdb uid=&id pwd=&pass connection=global);

create table akwork.sastab as select * from connection to db ( select * from #mlist2);

QUIT;RUN;
ENDRSUBMIT;
```

Global temp tables require db admin rights, correct? I don't have that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for Sybase in general:
If you add a semi-colon at the end of your SQL statement, then the temp table will be persistent through the active session.

I've tested this for the SAS's SQL pass-through and it works between different `rsubmit` statements hours apart.

Therefore, use this instead:

```
execute(select *
    into #mylist2 
    from #mylist A 
    JOIN DBTABLE B on A.VAR = B.VAR;
) by db;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use a LIBNAME command to make a connection that can persist between independent PROC SQL sessions. Without having the libref created there is no connection between SAS and the database that can be kept active.

It least that is how it works with SAS/Access to Teradata.

```
libname tdwork teradata server=blahdb user=&id password=&pass connection=global;
...
proc sql;
  connect to teradata as db (server=blahdb user=&id password=&pass connection=global);
  ...
quit;
...
proc sql;
  connect to teradata as db (server=blahdb user=&id password=&pass connection=global);
  ...
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can precede a temporary table with a double hash (`##`) to allow it to persist across connections (so long as they are by the same user).  Be sure to clean up after yourself though..